# Create a property from a structure

Tags: vb.net, properties

I am tying to create a property for a usercontrol to set values based a structure that I have defined. Here is the code that I am using to create the structure and the property

```
Private fooList As List(Of Structure_Foo)

    Public Structure Structure_Foo
        Dim a As Integer
        Dim b As Integer
    End Structure

    Public Property Foo As List(Of Structure_Foo)
        Get
            Return fooList
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Structure_Foo))
            fooList = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

[image: Example of the requirement]

I need to be able to set the values for the structure as list collection from the designer property window as shown in the image above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your structure to

```
Public Structure Structure_Foo
    Public Property a As Integer
    Public Property b As Integer
End Structure
```

The Visual Studio editor only lists properties, not fields. That goes for all the attribute dialogs. If you want to edit fields you probably need to create a custom designer for the control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h51z5c0x.aspx

Comment: This wasn't in the original question but is there anyway I could extend the properties inside the Structure_Foo to be coming from another structure. Eg. Instead of Public Property a As Integer, how can I make it to be like Public Property a As Another_Structure.

Comment: Sure, a structure is a value type like any other. However for its properties to appear like you want you need to wrap properties of your first structure around the other. Ill update my answer later with that when i get back to the office

Comment: I posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241527/vb-net-setting-properties-of-user-control .. This question doesn't exactly seem to satisfy my requirement just discovered it a bit late. Pls be kind enough to look into it as well if you got the time.