# Vb.Net setting properties of user control

Tags: vb.net, properties

I have a custom user control & I am looking to set some of its properties from the designer. The properties will be coming from a structure. Here is the current code

```
Private fooList As Foo_structure

    Public Structure Foo_structure
        Public Property a As Integer
        Public Property b As Integer
        Public Property c As Extras
    End Structure

    Public Structure Extras
        Public Property precision As Integer
        Public Property light As String
    End Structure

    Public Property foo As Foo_structure
        Get
            Return fooList
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Foo_structure)
            fooList = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I need to be able to set the properties of the Foo_structure from the designer properties panel like the eg shown in the image below.

[image: example]

Comment: you need to write a TypeConverter which inherits from `ExpandableObjectConverter`  but I also think at least Foo needs to be a class so that `Extras` can be instanced otherwise is will be Nothing and cause all sorts of problems

Comment: what is `fooList`? a simple foo variable or an actual list of them?

Comment: fooList is just a variable name.. :)

Comment: I haven't used TypeConverter & ExpandableObjectConverter, can you point me to a starters resource or give an example code.

Answer (score 5):

You are going to need a `TypeConverter` to collapse foo into a string; and convert back from it.  The nested Type means you need to write another one for `Extras`.  You will probably need to use some attributes to handle designer persistence.

To start, I think you need to change at least Foo_structure to a Class, otherwise there is no way to add code to instance `Extras` (also no way to create a Foo instance).  This should get you started (changed some names):

```
' Foo converted to Class:
<TypeConverter("FooItemConverter")>
Public Class FooBar
    <DefaultValue(0)>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
    Public Property Foo As Integer

    <DefaultValue(0)>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
    Public Property Bar As Integer

   <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
   <NotifyParentProperty(True)>
   <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Property Ex As Extras

    Public Sub New(a1 As Integer, b2 As Integer)
        Foo = a1
        Bar = b2
        Ex = New Extras    ' do not want NOTHING flying about
    End Sub

End Class
```

`DefaultValue` does not do what you may think it does.  It tells the IDE to serialize the value for a property when the current value does not equal the Default.  `DesignerSerializationVisibility` tells VS to save the value for a property.  Foo and Bar both need these.

Ex/Extra is different.  `NotifyParentProperty` allows FooBar to be notified when a Extra property value has changed so the IDE window is updated, internal "DirtyFlag" set etc; `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` tells VS that we know we cant save Ex as a value, so save the contents.

Then comes the FooItemConverter.  This will be the thing that displays the string you want in the Props window AND creates a Foo item from that string:

```
Friend Class FooItemConverter
   Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

   ' tells the IDE what conversions it can handle:
    Public Overrides Function CanConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                              destType As Type) As Boolean
        If destType = GetType(String) Then
            ' Yes I Can
            Return True
        End If
        ' Probably have to also say YES to an InstanceDescriptor 
        Return MyBase.CanConvertTo(context, destType)
    End Function
```

After that a `ConvertTo` function is used to convert foo to a string.  Something like this:

```
Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                culture As Globalization.CultureInfo,
                                value As Object, destType As Type) As Object
    If destType = GetType(String) Then

        Dim f As FooBar = CType(value, FooBar)
        Return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", 
                f.foo.ToString, 
                f.bar.ToString, 
                f.Ex.ToString)

       ' outputs: X, Y, <ex>
       ' where Ex is what we use in the ExtraItemConverter

    End If

    Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, destType)
End Function
```

If `ExtraItemConverter.ConvertTo` use a format of `"({0} / {1})"` then the control contents will show as: `F, B, (P / L)`  where F=Foo, B=Bar etc.

To make it work, you need 4 procedures: CanConvertTo, ConvertTo, CanConvertFrom, ConvertFrom all responding to string.  You *probably* will be able to just use the `<DefaultValue>` attribute for persistence.

`FooItemConverter.ConvertFrom` will have to know how to create an object from that string. Normally, that is done like this:

```
' parse the string you made and create a Foo
Dim els As String() = str.Split(","c)
Return New myFoo(Convert.ToInt32(els(0)), Convert.ToInt32(els(1)))
```

Note that the 3rd element is ignored as that is actually for the `ExtraItemConverter` to handle.  That converter would be very similar.

So, you will first have to decide whether to cling to the structure or use a class (another pro for a Class is that 99.999% of the examples you find will be Class based). [These guys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) know a lot about `TypeConverters`.